# How do I filter by occurrences count in another table in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Here are my models:

```
class Zoo(TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    zoo = models.ForeignKey(Zoo, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='diffbot_results')
```

I would like to run a query like this:

```
Zoo.objects.filter("WHERE zoo.id IN (select zoo_id from animal_table having count(*) > 10 group by zoo_id)")
```

Comment: btw, there's an error in your sql - the `HAVING` clause must follow the `GROUP BY`; i corrected it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a [raw queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/):

```
>>> from testapp.models import Zoo, Animal
>>> z1, z2 = Zoo(), Zoo()
>>> z1.save(), z2.save()
(None, None)
>>> z1_animals = [Animal(zoo=z1) for ii in range(5)]
>>> z2_animals = [Animal(zoo=z2) for ii in range(15)]
>>> x = [a.save() for a in z1_animals+z2_animals]
>>> qs = Zoo.objects.raw("select * from testapp_zoo zoo WHERE zoo.id IN (select zoo_id from testapp_animal group by zoo_id having count(1) > 10)")
>>> list(qs)
[<Zoo: Zoo object (2)>]
```

In theory, per [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in), it should be possible to pass in a queryset to a regular `.filter(id__in=<queryset>)`, but the queryset must only select one column, and I can't find a way of adding the `HAVING` clause without also causing the queryset to select a num_animals column, preventing it from being used with an `__in` filter expression.